# Many zombie processes and they are all mongosh from Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, zombie-process

Logging into my Linux server which hosts many Docker containers, I saw a warning that "There are 320 zombie processes." That seems bad! You can see which processes are involved using:

```bash
ps axo stat,ppid,pid,comm | grep -w defunct
```

They are all `mongosh` and that only comes from one of the docker containers running the MongoDB server. What is wrong here? And are these a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zombie processes exist because they were killed and some other process is still waiting for info from them. Not a big deal but probably unwanted.

My server is running via Docker Compose. In the compose file I had a health check which is using `mongosh` to ping MongoDB internally. The timing of that was too short and it was being killed:

```
healthcheck:
      test: "mongosh ... --eval 'quit(db.runCommand({ ping: 1 }).ok ? 0 : 1)' || exit 1"
      interval: 30s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 1s  # <-- That start_period is the problem
      timeout: 10s
```

Setting the `start_period` to `10s` and restarting the container fixed everything. Zombie apocalypse averted!

Comment: Generally spot-on. One minor correction: a zombie is created when a process's parent (adoptive or otherwise) is _not_ `wait()`ing for the status of a process that died -- calling `waitpid()` removes the "tombstone" entry (with exit status / terminal signal / &c) from the process table and returns the data previously contained; so it's the opposite of waiting-but-unfulfilled, caused instead by _nothing_ waiting.